Gitlab Runner cannot delete locked file with Flutter project
Been having this issue recently trying to simple build a flutter project in Gitlab
It fails even before getting to the first stage with this error that doesnt really say what the error is. It just exits with status 1
Running with gitlab-runner 16.10.0 (81ab07f6)
  on flutter_runner Akpoaw1Da, system ID: s_d5fffb6b048e
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (powershell) executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on MAIN-PC...
Getting source from Git repository
00:10
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/Akpoaw1Da/0/MYAPP/.git/
Checking out 7484d311 as detached HEAD (ref is development)...
warning: failed to remove build/app/intermediates/dex/release/minifyReleaseWithR8/classes.dex: Invalid argument
warning: failed to remove build/app/intermediates/dex/release/minifyReleaseWithR8/classes2.dex: Invalid argument
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Here is my yml file
image: ghcr.io/cirruslabs/flutter

stages:  
  - deploy
before_script:
  - git config --system core.longpaths true

# Deploy release
deployFirebase:
  stage: deploy    
  only:
    - development #only work on dev branch
  script: 
    - ls
    - flutter build apk --release 

